# What happened to the probes at the end of Life?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, life

In *Life*, David's probe was supposed to go into outer space with Calvin trapped into it, and the probe with Miranda was supposed to go to Earth.
At the end we can see that the David's probe has been landed with Calvin and David inside.

How was that supposed to happen? Probably I missed something.

Comment: I think life-boats and not probes...

Comment: I saw these things were mentioned as `probes` in another question abt this movie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How was that supposed to happen?

### It wasn't.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_(2017_film)) makes this clear.

> David leads Calvin into his pod and launches into space as Miranda launches hers. **One of the pods hits debris and is knocked off course**. Calvin then lunges at David and attacks him as he struggles to send his pod into deep space, The earthbound pod performs a controlled re-entry and lands in the ocean (probably somewhere in the south pacific) near a boat with two fishermen. As they approach the pod and look inside, it is revealed to be David's...

Note it's doesn't say *which* pod is damaged & knocked off course.

This is a classic movie **misdirect** and **cliff-hanger ending**. We're *supposed* to think that the pod that landed on Earth is the "safe" one carrying Miranda.... **but it's not and the threat isn't over**

Comment: ok then. thanx.

Comment: I agree completely with this answer, although it's worth noting that if you're paying attention you can tell it's happening in the moment.  We know Miranda's pod was behind David's after leaving ISS (because he launched first) and after the pods travel through the debris field, there's a scene where one pod goes up (away from the Earth) and the other goes down into the atmosphere.  The one that goes up was slightly behind the one that goes down.  It's not *clear* which is which (and that's on purpose, for sure,) but I suspected the switch from that moment until the reveal.

Comment: yep I watched this movie three times and it's really can bo noticed if to watch intentively ))